# React JS if clause not working properly inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i'm new at react and i'm trying to build a box where i can show data dynamically.

```
const Widget = ({type}) => {
let data = {
    title:"",
    increase: false,
    amount: 0,
    link:"View Billing",
    icon: <KeyboardArrowUpIcon classname={"icon"}/>

};
```

I did a switch case to take care of the various types that i received

```
  switch (type){
    case "Billing":
        data={
            title:"Billing",
            increase: false,
            amount: 4000,
            link:"View Billing",
            icon: <MonetizationOnOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
        };
        break;
```

I created the if clause in this way and i want to show an icon depending on the value of increase.

```
return(
  <div className="widget">
      <div className="left">
          <span className="title">{data.title}</span>
          <span className="counter">{data.amount}</span>
          <span className="link">{data.link}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
          <div className="percentage positive">

              {(data.increase)? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> + ["20"] : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/> + ["-13"]}
          </div>
          {data.icon}
      </div>
  </div>
```

)

But the result I'm having is

[image]

For some reason, that i don't know, this clause is not passing the icon.

```
                  {(data.increase)? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> + ["20"] : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/> + ["-13"]}
```

What am i doing wrong? I tried doing an if inside the div but i couldn't make it work but like this it kinda works but it doesn't recognize the icon

Comment: `<KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> + ["20"]` is trying to add an instance of ReactElement and an array consisting of one string, it won't work properly. Why are you trying to add them?

Comment: Avoid utilising javascript based concatenation

Comment: If you want to make them appear next to each other, you can try the following (using React Fragment): `<> <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> {"20"} </>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
return(
  <div className="widget">
      <div className="left">
          <span className="title">{data.title}</span>
          <span className="counter">{data.amount}</span>
          <span className="link">{data.link}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
          <div className="percentage positive">

              {
                data.increase? 
                  <>
                    <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> 20
                  </> : 
                  <>
                    <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/> -13
                  </>
              }
          </div>
          {data.icon}
      </div>
  </div>
);
```

The reason why it's not working is that you are trying to concat the component instance with an array which results in your Object object

Comment: That totally solves my problem! i didn't know i could insert a <> directly inside the {}. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This expression doesn't make any sense:

```
<KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> + ["20"]
```

You're trying to add a component to an array.  Neither of those things can be meaningfully *added* to anything.  The result is simply the engine converting them to strings and concatenating them.

If the goal is just to output the component and the string `"20"` then you can simply output them exactly as that.  For the JSX syntax you'd just wrap them in an enclosing element:

```
<><KeyboardArrowUpIcon/>20</>
```

With spaces for clarity:

```
<>
  <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/>
  20
</>
```

Comment: That totally works too! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Each React node needs to be under one container. You need to wrap your logic within a div or React.Fragment (shortly <></>).

```
{(data.increase) ? 
(<>
<KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> + ["20"]
</>) 
: (<>
<KeyboardArrowDownIcon/> + ["-13"]
</>)}
```

But I still do not understand why are you using square brackets for 20 and -13?
I do not know the logic of your app but I am feeling that your code might be like this.

```
{(data.increase) ? 
(<>
<KeyboardArrowUpIcon/>
<div>20</div>
</>) 
: (<>
<KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>
<div>-13</div>
</>)}
```

I hope this is the answer that you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped to understand it better. I was using the square brackets because i copy pasted the if clause from the react website and since it had the square brackets i left it there.